# how to resolve NoSuchElementException in java

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I wrote the code as shown:

what more should I include to remove this NoSuchElementFound Exception

I've tried including HasMoreElements(),HasNextInt() but that did'nt work either

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    t=input.nextInt();
    while(t>0)
    {
        int n=input.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
```

please try to modify this code so that i'll not get this exception.

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int n = input.nextInt();
            if (n > 0) {
                int a[] = new int[n];
            }
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            int n = input.nextInt();
            int a[] = new int[n];
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to declare 't'

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
int t=input.nextInt();
while(t>0)
{
    int n=input.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown to indicate that there are no more elements in buffer but your code is expecting one & based on the code that you have shared following two possibilities are expected:-

1. *Variable t isn't decremented* : you should add 't--' as last statement in your loop & also before any continue statement that you are using.
2. *The input itself is missing the required number of integers* : For this, you can take any of the approach suggested by either Matthew or Sachin. Since you are claiming hasNextInt() method isn't working, you should update the exception/error & your relevant code for better understanding of the situation.

Hope it helps!